# How to build array from a text file in C

Tags: c, string, file, text

Im writing a program where I insert strings that are from a text file into an array. I already have the insert function written, but im confused as how to run through the text file string by string.

Essentially in the main() function the program needs to setup an array, then run thought the file opened and use the insert function on each string in the file. So how would I go about taking each string, using it in the insert function and then moving on to the next string in the file.

If more clarification is needed let me know! Thanks.

Updated with Insert and main functions:

The insert function inserts the string word into Table, which should be maintained  in  sorted  order. it Returns n+1 if the string is successfully inserted;   otherwise returns n. It uses binary search.

```
int insert(char *word, char *Table[], int n){

    int low = 0;
    int high = n;
    int mid;
    int index = -1;
    int k;

    while (low < high)
    {
        mid = low  +  (high - low)/2;
        if (strcmp(Table[mid], word) == 0)
        {
            index = mid;
            break;
        }
        else if (strcmp(Table[mid], word) < 0)
            low = mid  +  1;
        else
            high = mid - 1;
    }
    if (index != -1 && index < n)
        return n;

    for (index = 0; index < n; index++)
    {
        if (strcmp(Table[index], word) < 0)
            continue;
        else
            break;
    }
    for (k = n-1; k >= index; k--)
    {
        Table[k + 1] = Table[k];
    }
    Table[index] = strdup(word);

    return n + 1;
}
```

Main:

Command line should be something like this "./concordance 15 < input.txt"

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

FILE *fp = fopen(argv[3], "r");
int n = atoi(argv[1]);
int insert;
char *Table[n];
```

Im stuck in the main function so its incomplete.
Also the a "word" in this file, which I meant by string, is classified with a punctuation character of space, period, comma, semicolon,colon,   exclamation 
point, double quote, question mark, and newline character. But apostrophe is still considered part of the word.

Comment: How do you define a string?

Comment: Post what you have already please.  The insert function's signature is especially important, as is memory allocation for your strings.  Also, we need to know the file format; are your strings delimited by commas? Nulls? Newlines?  If you can't provide these i have a feeling your question will get closed.

Comment: will do give me a few mins

Comment: Your program can cause too many problems as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest first opening the file with `FILE` and reading the line using `fgets` as such:

```
char* str;
FILE* fp;
fp = fopen("YOUR_FILE_NAME", "r"); // open for reading
if (fp == NULL)
{
    // say some error message
    return -1;
}
fgets(str, SOME_LARGE_NUMBER, fp);
```

Then either use `strtok` as such:

```
char* tok;
do {
    tok = strtok(str, " ");
    // HANDLE STRING <-- This is where you would use your insert thing
} while(tok != NULL);
```

Or manually parse the string yourself by looping through each character in the string from `gets` which I'm not going to write because it's somewhat long.

Comment: so is the strtok used inside of the if (fp != NULL)?

Comment: @JoshFriedman It can be. Let me edit the code to make it more understandable.

Comment: @JoshFriedman The null check is there to make sure you actually open a file. i.e. if you used `fopen` with an incorrect file name, then `fp` would be NULL